# WCF multiple host headers

Tags: wcf, header, host

I have created a wcf service that i have uploaded to my host (using IIS). Everything works fine.
So, if i go to http://www.mydomain.com/path/Service.svc it works fine.
If i go to http://mydomain.com/path/Service.svc i get a resource not found error.

I have created a clientaccesspolicy.xml under the path folder which contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<access-policy>
<cross-domain-access>
<policy>
<allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction">
<domain uri="http://*"/>
<domain uri="http://www.mydomain.com/path/*" />
<domain uri="http://mydomain.com/path/*" />
</allow-from>
<grant-to>
<resource include-subpaths="true" path="/"/>
</grant-to>
</policy>
</cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

but it doesnt seem to have any effect. Have looked on the web but didnt find a decent explanation on how this is solved. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should to add more host headers on IIS. Take a look here: [How to Create Multiple Websites with one IP address](http://www.iisanswers.com/Top10FAQ/t10-hostheaders.htm)

Comment: The issue i am having is with the host though. I am not able to access these tools there.